# How to check existing SQLite db in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to check SQLite database table record . Whether table row is exist then update or delete my table row or.When I run my app the table row insert duplicate.How to avoid it . I want to insert newly record when I run first time , when open the activity second time my database is update. I have tried but db is not show record there.Please help me.Thanks to appreciates

Here is my  code

```
public boolean Exists(String _id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select Company_Id from Company where Company_Id = ?",
                new String[]{_id});
        boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
        cursor.close();
        return exists;
    }
```

My fragment code

```
if(jsonStr != null)
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String jsonResult = jsonObj.toString().trim();
                Log.e("jsonResult ", " = " + jsonResult);



                JSONObject companyList = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Get_CompanyResult");
                Log.e("companyList ", " = " + companyList.toString());

                JSONArray jarr = companyList.getJSONArray("CompanylList");
                Log.e("jarr ", " = " + jarr.toString());


                 for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobCompanyDetails = jarr.getJSONObject(i);

                    str_CompanyId = jobCompanyDetails.getString("Company_ID");
                    str_CompanyName = jobCompanyDetails.getString("Company_Name");

                    Log.e("str_CompanyId ", " = " + str_CompanyId);
                    Log.e("str_CompanyName ", " = " + str_CompanyName);

                     if(dbhelper.Exists(str_CompanyId))
                     {
                         Log.e("Row is Already ","Exist");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                            dbhelper.insertCompany(str_CompanyId, str_CompanyName);
                            Log.e("Data insert into  ", " Company Table Succesively !!! = ");
                     }


                 }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method

```
public boolean isIDExist(String _id){

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query(Company, new String[] { KEY_your_id}, KEY_your_id + "=?" ,

            new String[] { String.valueOf( _id)}, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null){

                if(cursor.getCount() == 0){

                    cursor.close();
                    db.close();
                    return false;

                }else{

                    cursor.close();
                    db.close();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this

```
public boolean Exists(String _id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select Company_Id from Company where Company_Id ='"+ String _id + "'", null);
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest way to do this is to create a Primary Key in the table, and then use INSERT OR REPLACE command instead of just using INSERT. 
INSERT OR REPLACE will automatically REPLACE the existing row when it encounters a Primary Key violation, with the new data being inserted.

In this case, you can have OrgId as the Primary Key and if you have some record like:

```
ORGID     ORGNAME
1          ABC
```

and you insert like   INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ORG_MASTER(1,'EFG'), the table will now have one row like

```
 ORGID     ORGNAME
    1          EFG
```

Hope this helps :)